# Why can't an inherited protected constructor be made public?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance, constructor

Consider:

```
class A
{
protected:
    A(int) {}
    void f(int) {}

public:
    A() {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::A;
    using A::f;
};

int main()
{
    B().f(1); // ok
    B(1); // error: 'A::A(int)' is protected within this context
}
```

Why can't an inherited `protected` constructor be made `public`, while an inherited `protected` member function can?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unlike other members, the accessibility of the using-declaration that introduced the [inherited constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) is ignored.

[[namespace.udecl]/19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#19),

(emphasis mine)

> A synonym created by a [***using-declaration***](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#nt:using-declaration) has the usual accessibility for a [***member-declaration***](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#nt:member-declaration). A [***using-declarator***](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#nt:using-declarator) that names a constructor does not create a synonym; instead, the additional constructors are accessible **if they would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class, and the accessibility of the [*using-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#nt:using-declaration) is ignored**.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the inherited constructor can be made public, but not just the way you wrote it. You can define your `B` class as follows:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B() {}

    B(int x) : A(x) {}  // instead of using A::A(int)
    using A::f;
};
```

(see it on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WAxh8-))

Perhaps the standard committee thought that saying `using A::A` would be a bit ambiguous, since a constructor of the base class is not exactly the same thing as a constructor of the subclass.